# when ASP.NET core web API app connecting call WCF service API, how to authenticate

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, wcf-binding

I am developing a C# backend app using ASP.NET core web API application. Inside this API, I need to call some API(WCF SOAP service) from database. For this WCF service, we were provided pre-built .dll, so will not use adding service reference. When calling these WCF service, have to pass my windows credential to let WCF service know I am a qualified user before use the service. Now I am stuck on how I can pass my credential to this WCF. What is the right architecture to use.(Screen shot is showing some endpoint of the WCF service)
Adding some background info, In our react frontend, will call these ASP.NET core web API to get data back from WCF, and show it on frontend.
I am new to C# and .Net core. Please share some insight. Thanks a lot. Happy New Year!!!

I did the ASP.NET core web API part. but could not figure out the right way to authenticate when connecting to WCF API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Have a similar situation here and don't know the best way to get the data from the WCF service to return to the client.